# Scala Parser Combinators :Extract List of a type

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am writing parser and grammer using scala.util.parsing.combinator . 
My input is `":za >= 1 alok && :ft == 9"`

```
case class Expression(op1:Operand,operator:Operator,op2:Operand)

def word: Parser[String] = """[a-z\\\s]+""".r ^^ { _.toString }

def colonWord:Parser[Operand]=":"~> word ^^{case variable => Operand(variable)}

def constant:Parser[Operand]="""^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\s-]*""".r ^^ {case constant => Operand(constant)}

def expression:Parser[Expression] = colonWord ~ operator ~ constant  ^^{ case op1~operator~op2 => Expression(op1, operator, op2)}

def expressions = expression ~ opt(" && " ~> expression)*
```

but when I parse sample String , the result is not expected. The second expression after `&&` is not parsed. Please note there can be multiple expression joined using `&&`.

When i execute:

```
val expr= ":za >= 1 alok && :ft == 9"
    parse(expressions, expr) match {
      case Success(matched, _) => println(matched)
      case ..}
```

Output is :

```
List((Expression(za ,>= ,1 alok )~None))
```

I dont see the second expression being parsed. Can anyone help what have i missed here?

**EDIT**
**-----------------------------------**

The requirement is to get `List[Expression]`.
when I say, incorporting the changes mentioned in Ans :

```
def expressions = expression ~ ("&&" ~> expression)*
```

The return type of expressions is not List[Expression]. For eg:
If I write another def :

```
case class Condition(exprs: List[Expression], st:Statement)
def condition = expressions ~","~statement ^^{
    case exprs~commaa~statement => Condition(exprs,statement) //This is giving error.
```

the error is:
    type mismatch; found : ~[Expression,Expression]] required: Expressions.

So how do i convert [Expression, Expression] to List[Expressions]?

Thanks

Comment: In your output `List((Expression(za ,>= ,1 alok )~None))`. Try to notice that extra space after `1 alok`. And extra space is the culprit, as your next `expressions` parser expects two `expression`s to be delimited by a `<space>&&<space>`

Comment: That is why, it is a good practice to have `<space>` as a first class member of your grammar. Don't ever belittle space.

Comment: Thanks. Yes , that is the problem . I tried removing spaces from <space>&&<space>. It worked in this case. But i gave another expression => ":za >= 1&&:ft == 9&&:wq == 12" , In this case it took 2 expression , rather than 3 . 
The output i get is List((Expression(za ,>= ,1)~Some(Expression(ft ,== ,9))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correction needed was:

```
expression ~ opt("&&" ~> expression)*
```

Remove space across `&&` and it should work. This is because you are already covering space in your `constant` parser.

Edit:
Based on edited question, is this what you want:

```
 def expressions = expression ~ (("&&" ~> expression)*) ^^{
    case x ~ y => x :: y
  }
```

Now the return type of `expressions` is `List[Expression]`. Your `condition` will now compile

Comment: Thanks. Yes , that is the problem . I tried removing spaces from <space>&&<space>. It worked in this case. But i gave another expression => ":za >= 1&&:ft == 9&&:wq == 12" , In this case it took 2 expression , rather than 3 . The output i get is List((Expression(za ,>= ,1)~Some(Expression(ft ,== ,9))))

Comment: I believe the problem is also with def expressions = expression ~ opt(" && " ~> expression)*  . I was expecting this to return me List[Expression] . But it returns [Expression, Option[Expression]]

Comment: because you have `opt` in `opt(" && " ~> expression)`. Now since you are using `*` which means `0 or more` you do not need that `opt`.

Comment: But this would not solve the problem . To make the problem more clearer , I have edited it.